# Email address validation on Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory

Can we add a email address validation while configuring policies for signup/signin pages on Azure Active Directory B2C? We require that users should register email addresses only from one specific account (@xyz.com) and not their social accounts.

Comment: Please provide some code / settings you tried by yourself. Thanks.

Comment: There is no code or setting that I am able to find to implement this functionality. Hence I posted this question.

Comment: Hi, @Rinks. One more thing that I want to confirmed is why you just allow for one type account. If this is for one organization, I recommend you can use Azure AD B2B, not B2C. If you just want to use B2C, I'm afraid you cannot achieve what you want .

Comment: Hi @WayneYang-MSFT, we can't go for B2B because there is no direct communication between 2 organizations (the host and client). The web app has to be public facing and more clients can be added in future. I found a way of  implementing this by creating custom policies under Identity Experience Framework. However, custom policy is under 'Public Preview' and not 'General Availability'. Hence seems a bit risky to implement and make it live using features which is not GA.

Comment: @Rinks, Oh, I see.